# Transferring from Vector to Vector

Tags: java, vector

I am currently attempting to pull data out from a file of co-ordinates, into a vector as a string, then pull the data out of this vector, and convert it from a string into a series of points and then place it into a second  Vector.

I can't find the solution anywhere online. I have the code for the first vector, and the code to transform it into doubles to be used by the  vector. But I need to know how to pull the data out of the first vector!

Im new to Java so I apologise if this is a really simple question!

Here is the code i have written so far.. i dont have a driver yet so i cant test it.
sorry in advance!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PointField {

     String ID;
     Vector<String> v;
     Vector<Point> v1;

     public PointField() {
           v = new Vector<String>(); 
           this.v1 = new Vector<Point>();
           this.ID = new String();
     }

     public String getID() {
           return this.ID;
     } 

     public Vector<String> getv() {
           return v;
     } 

     public Vector<Point> getv1() {
           return this.v1;
     } 

//Read all the lines from a file
     public Vector<String> getString(String fileName) throws Exception{

// Variable declarations
           File inputFile;
           FileInputStream inputStream;
           InputStreamReader inputStreamRead;
           BufferedReader br;

// Make the objects needed
           inputFile = new File(fileName);
           inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
           inputStreamRead = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
           br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamRead);

// read all the lines and call getPoint method
           while (this.ID!= null) {
               this.ID = br.readLine();
               v.addElement(this.ID);
}
// DOESNT WORK FROM HERE Get String out of Vector v and make it return it as String ID
 public String getString(Vector<String> v) {
      Iterator<String> it;
      it = this.v.iterator();
      while(it.hasNext()) {
      this.ID = (String)it.next();
      }

             return ID; 
 }

//* Get String into two doubles and assign to x,y variables     
     public Point makePoints(String s, String delim) {
           while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
               st = new StringTokenizer(s, delim);  
               p = new Point(x,y);
               x = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
               y = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
          }     
            return p;       
    }


}
```

Comment: ive improved the code so it works up until the iterator bit!

Comment: As a general rule, you should use ArrayList instead of the older Vector class.

Comment: Please please please format the code properly when you edit it...

Comment: sorry! ive formatted the code so its more readable!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can find usefull [this one](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#transform%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Transformer%29)
from the [Apache Collection Util](http://commons.apache.org/collections/)
Or in that library you can find various method to work with the list (transform, filter, etc..)

The problem you have is the iterator...istead of to `it = this.v.iterator();` do an instance variable with that iterator

Answer (score 0):

Your `getString()` method will only ever return the last element of the Vector, because it creates a new Iterator each time, goes through all the elements, then returns the last one.

I'm not quite sure why you are adding elements to one Vector, then converting them to put in a second Vector - couldn't you do this in one step?

It looks like you are reading the lines into the first Vector OK.

I suggest you then iterate over that vector, convert each element to the new form using a method call (a revised version of `makePoints` that processes one point at a time, and then add the result to v2, if you stil want to use 2 Vectors.

```
Iterator<String> it = v.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
   Point p = makePoint(it.next());
   v2.add(p);
}
```

Comment: I am just trying to get it done the only way i know how! So im going to first try and get it working for two vectors, then if i have time i can try and simplify the code to only use one vector!

Comment: I have now editied the code to use the iterator method you suggested, and im now making the makepoints method which the iterator uses - but there is an issue with my stringtokenizer; i get the error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't call `makePoints()`, so I can't help without more info. And you call `st.nextToken()` twice for every `st.hasMoreTokens()`, which is risky.

Comment: the makepoints method is trying to assign xy co-ordinates from the data in the file we load to the first vector.